# How to execute standalone .dmn files by passing input data in the form of pandas dataframe?

Tags: drools, camunda, kie, dmn, feel-language

I'm a complete beginner in BPM tools.
This is my use case:

1. I'll create .dmn files (very light; not that complex).
2. Execute those .dmn files by passing data in python pandas dataframes.

I've gotten a good hang of step-1 (thanks to Youtube videos).
Doubts in step-2:
2.1) How to execute a standalone .dmn file?
2.2) I can pass the input data in the form of json as well (to the KIE server's API point) but is there any optimised solution? (my input can range from 10 rows to 10k rows.

Any sort of help or direction would mean a lot. Stuck on it for for almost a month now.

Thanks

I tried the KIE Extended Services sandbox, I'm able to run my standalone .dmn files but I'm not sure if I can use this in a production env. I'd prefer a KIE server which can execute my standalone .dmn files.

PS: not sure if my approach is right or not.